# How to write a function which takes a filename and returns a string with all \n characters replaced by "_"

Tags: python, thonny

I'm trying to write a function that takes a filename and returns a string with all \n characters replaced by "_" but my code is not returning anything in the shell (comes up with no errors) but I am unsure what I'm doing wrong! We haven't learned to use the 'with' operator, just for and in.

```
def replace_space(filename):
    text_str = ''
    wordfile = open(filename)
    text_str = wordfile.read()
    wordfile.close()
    return text_str.replace("\n", "_")

print(replace_space("roses.txt"))
```

Comment: Your code works for me, so I assume it's a Thonny issue. Although, your `text_str = ''` is redundant.

Comment: I just tried it in Thonny, and it worked. Can you show the contents of `roses.txt`?

Comment: Yes! Everything is running fine. Output replaces `\n` with `'_'` , Check your `roses.txt` file.